# ORDER BY "ENUM field" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, sql-order-by

There is a field 'noticeBy' enum('email','mobile','all','auto','nothing') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'auto'. As it known ordering by ENUM field performs relative to its index. However, how it possible make order by its values?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As documented under [Sorting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html#enum-sorting):

> `ENUM` values are sorted based on their index numbers, which depend on the order in which the enumeration members were listed in the column specification. For example, `'b'` sorts before `'a'` for `ENUM('b', 'a')`. The empty string sorts before nonempty strings, and `NULL` values sort before all other enumeration values.
>
> To prevent unexpected results when using the `ORDER BY` clause on an `ENUM` column, use one of these techniques:
>
> - Specify the `ENUM` list in alphabetic order.
> - Make sure that the column is sorted lexically rather than by index number by coding `ORDER BY CAST(col AS CHAR)` or `ORDER BY CONCAT(col)`.

Per the second bullet, you can therefore sort on the column after it has been [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html) to a string:

```
ORDER BY CAST(noticeBy AS CHAR)
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you!  Odd that this best (highest voted) and accepted answer is not at the top?  If it's for lack of comments, hoping this one will help.

Comment: @jtubre: There are three sort buttons between the question and answers: "Active", "Oldest" and "Votes".  If you sort by votes, this answer should be top?  But it won't be top under the other sort orders (it used to be that accepted answers were pinned to the top regardless, but [StackOverflow changed that a few months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/outdated-answers-accepted-answer-is-now-unpinned-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 82):

This also works:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(noticeBy, 'all','auto','email','mobile','nothing')
```

(I don't believe that there is a setting to achieve this, you have to provide the sort-values.)

Comment: This way of sorting ENUM can be very useful some cases! It's really works, I have tried it:)

Comment: perfect exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 33):

You can define your order however you wish:

```
ORDER BY CASE noticeBy
           WHEN 'email' THEN 1
           WHEN 'mobile' THEN 2
           WHEN 'all' THEN 3
           WHEN 'auto' THEN 4
           ELSE 5
         END
```

This will return the rows in the following order: email, mobile, all, auto, nothing.

Comment: It is what I need :) Thanks, Fabian.

Comment: Thanks @Fabian It's helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The best option to me:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'publish','not-publish','expirated','deleted'), creation DESC
```

Status is the field in my BBDD, and values in '' are the values that has in enum options.

I hope that help u too! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to sort enum results by the "ENUM" field and also make sure the values are in DESCENDING order. My enum had the following values: `'Open','Closed'`

So when I used `ORDER BY CAST(status AS CHAR)`, the results were in this order:

```
Closed
Open
Open
```

But I wanted the `Open` status tickets to be shown first and then the `Closed` tickets. So I used the following:

`ORDER BY CAST(status AS CHAR) DESC`

This gave me the order that I was looking for i.e.

```
Open
Open
Closed
```

**Summary:**

Just using `ORDER BY CAST` on an enum did not seem to help. To sort the results in a specific order, mentioning `ASC` or `DESC` as well, did the trick.