# ORDER BY “ENUM field” with an calculated field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, enums

My situation is a bit more complicated than [order-by-enum-field-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603907/)

My SQL is:

```
SELECT `a`.`ChannelID`,
  `a`.`CategoryID`,
  `a`.`Country`,
  `a`.`LocalName`,
  if((`a`.`Type` = 'FreeText'
      AND a.IsHybrid = 'YES'), 'Hybrid', 
      if(`a`.`Type` = 'FreeText'
        AND a.IsHybrid = 'NO', 'FreeText', a.Type)) AS TYPE,
  `a`.`IsHybrid`
FROM `ProCatCountry` AS `a`
  INNER JOIN `ProCat` AS `b` ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
ORDER BY FIELD(a.TYPE, 'FreeText', 'Hybrid', 'Structured') ASC
```

But the order is not correct, first `FreeText` records appeared then `Hybrid` then `FreeText` appeared again.

Field `TYPE` is enum, and I want to order by this field, meanwhile, a value which does not included in enum list - the calculated one called `Hybrid` should also be ordered by correctly. How can I do with this situation?

Originally, there was a `TYPE` field ambiguous error, thanks to @Jens, after changed to `a.TYPE`, the ambiguous error was resolved.

Comment: Do you have a `type` column in both tables?

Comment: @juergend Yes, I have `TYPE` field too in `ProCat` table

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the table alias in `order by` statement:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(a.TYPE, 'FreeText', 'Hybrid', 'Structured') ASC
```

Becuase it is a column of both tables.

Comment: Hey, the ambiguous error vanished after I added to `a.TYPE` but new problem appeared, I've modified my question, please take a look, Thank you!

Comment: @Phenix It is not a good idea to exit the question. You should update your question that the community see that the question has changed. So it is better to let the original question visible and add a checktion `UPDATE`

Comment: Oh, sorry, how can I update the question? I've just edited it.

Comment: @Phoenix You missunderstand me. You should use the edit function. But you should not override the original information. You shout add the update after the original question.

Comment: Now I understand, OK! I made a sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a423/1, please see