# Sequelize: sort by enum cases

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model (`Article`) with a field (the name is `type`) of type `ENUM('source', 'translated')` and would like to return 1 article ordered by the type field. Source articles should be returned before translated articles. Something like:

```
Article.findOne(order: [
    {
        type: [
            'source',
            'translated'
        ]
    }
]);
```

Unfortunately there appears to be no built-in solution for sorting by enums. Instead I probably have to sort [by case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603993/45974), but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this with Sequelize.

What would be the conventional approach here?

Answer (score 3):

Sorting by CASE is hard to do in sequelize, but sort by field (the second answer in your linked post) should be possible:

```
order: sequelize.fn('field', sequelize.col('type'), 'source', 'translated')
```

It's only supported by mysql as far as I know though

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by CASE you should use sequelize.literal

```
order: sequelize.literal(`case when type='source then '0' when type='tranlated' then '1' else type end`)
```